# Angular6 click event is not triggered in a loop

Tags: javascript, angular, html, css

When I click on the Test, the click function should be called.
But nothing is triggered.

HTML componrnt:

```
<div class="row m-0 justify-content-between" *ngFor="let i of 
k[currentk]?.details | keys">

    <div (click)="test(i.name)">{{i.name}}</div>

</div>
```

ts component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-test',
 templateUrl: './test.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() {}

 ngOnInit() {}

 test(name){
   alert('Hello world');
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, to Stack overflow . Please take the [tour](stackoverflow.com/tour)  and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal , Complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Comment: post your test function code

Comment: @sid see the question i posted it

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing it right. You don't need the *ngFor loop in your div tag. SImply remove it and your code shall work.

Comment: My bad I should added the dynamic name.

Comment: post a screenshot of your result on the page on any image uploading site and share the link

Comment: i need to see the result to give a solution